# File extension for JSON import/export format

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, file-extension

The official file extension for a file containing JSON data is `.json`. However after using MongoDB for a while, I realize this extension is actually used for two types of JSON formats:

1. A file containing one single JSON document with optional pretty printing, including line breaks.
2. A file which contains multiple lines of minified JSON documents. Here each line is JSON, but the entire file is not valid JSON itself.

For example, the [mongoexport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) manual uses `output.json` in many of its examples to create a file with many lines of JSON. However a parser that assumes the first format will probably choke on this file.

Are there any conventional alternate file extensions to distinguish the two scenarios?

Comment: The only way I see to distinguish both would be min.json, but that couldn't eventually be missunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that multiple JSON objects is clearly no valid JSON. The spec states that `JSON-text = ws value ws` and `value = false / null / true / object / array / number / string`, which means it doesn't allow for multiple objects.

There is an effort to make this their own format called NDJSON. The current first version of the spec is over here: https://github.com/ndjson/ndjson-spec.

We still need a bit more publicity about this standard, because ndjson is often incorrectly labeled as being `.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of, and there is a good reason for that.

JSON was conceived as a data interchange format with low overhead. White space, unless quoted, is therefor ignored by any parser I am aware of (Java, Perl, Python, JavaScript).

Although white space is explicitly mentioned in [RFC7159: The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159), the grammar does not state that white space has a semantic meaning. What it does state in the grammar section is that white space is insignificant and in the parser section that all conforming parsers must obey the grammar. So regardless if there is white space or not, as long as the other requirements of JSON's grammar are met, it is a valid JSON document.

This leads to the fact that basically every parser will first remove any non quoted white space before it starts creating objects or ignores it in the first place.

So if a parser has a problem parsing either formats you mentioned, this can safely be considered a bug.

**Edit:** I didn't see the assumption that multiple objects in one document form an invalid JSON document. As far as I understand it, the RFC implicitly allows it to have multiple object, as it does not impose a limit on the number of tokens and does not explicitly prohibit a JSON text to contain multiple objects. This however, means that any application which parses JSON should expect to get an undefined number of objects instead of exactly one.